# How binding canvas children

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding

silverlight 4

```
              <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
            <Popup x:Name="contextMenu" IsOpen="False">
                <Border Background="#A5FBFBFB" CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="1" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="txbBusy" Content="isBusy"
                           Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="txbFree" Content="isFree"
                           Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Table}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Margin="10" 
    Background="AliceBlue"   Width="300" Height="300" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Canvas.Left="{Binding x, Converter={StaticResource KeyIntToDoubleConverter}}" Canvas.Top="{Binding y, Converter={StaticResource KeyIntToDoubleConverter}}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding x}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

TextBox - show number, but `Canvas.Left="{Binding x}"` - not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

[binding-canvas](http://simplecod.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/binding-canvas-%D0%B2-silverlight-4-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%E2%84%963/)

Answer (score 0):

'x' must be of type double, not int.

Comment: Laith, I add converter but this not helped me. I update my code in first post.

Comment: Did you try changing the int X to double X? Try that for testing purposes and see if it works. I've run into this problem before when using int's instead of double's. So, remove the converter and change your code to make X a double. Give that a try.

Comment: I changing (with converter) int X to Double Х and nothing has changed

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the only thing actually on the canvas is the ItemsControl.  This in turn uses a stackpanel by default which is where the generated children are added hence assigning Canvas.Left has no impact.

You need to place your Canvas inside a ItemsPanelTemplate which in turn is assigned as the value of ItemsControl ItemsPanel property.  This will cause the ItemsControl to generate the Canvas instead of the default StackPanel.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Table}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <Canvas Margin="10" 
            Background="AliceBlue"   Width="300" Height="300" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Border Canvas.Left="{Binding x}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                  <StackPanel>
                     <TextBox Text="{Binding x}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
               </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
```